# How to read STRING TABLE resources for given language into map

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, resources

I have translated strings for multiple languages in vs resource `.rc` files stored in `STRINGTABLE`

```
//english.rc

#pragma code_page(65001)
#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#include "afxres.h"
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)

LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    1000                    "SOME TEXT"
    7777                    "SOME TEXT"
END
#endif

//danish.rc
#pragma code_page(65001)
#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#include "afxres.h"
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_DANISH, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    1001                    "SOME TEXT IN DANISH"
    7777                    "SOME TEXT IN DANISH"
END
#endif
```

I want to load those resources to the map of [languageId : [(resourceId: value),...],...]

`std::map<long /*languageId*/, std::map<long /*resource id (1000, 7777, 1001)*/, std::string /*value*/>>`

I do not know how many resources are in the `.rc` files, I do not know resource Ids either (I expect there is some way to get all ids from the file, but I haven't found a way to do that so far)

**What I tried**

Iterating through resources via callback.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <map>

BOOL EnumResourceLanguagesCallback(HMODULE applicationModule, LPCTSTR resourceType, LPCTSTR resourceName, WORD languageId, std::map<long /*languageId*/, std::map<long /*resource id (e.g. 1000, 7777, 1001)*/, std::string /*resource value*/>> * pResources)
{
    HRSRC hResInfo = FindResourceEx(applicationModule, resourceType, resourceName, languageId);
    HGLOBAL hData = LoadResource(0, hResInfo);

    std::wstring values;
    values.assign((wchar_t*)LockResource(hData), SizeofResource(applicationModule, hResInfo));
    /* values string is either empty or contains garbage or sometimes partial string with some of the resources in the rc file - depends on the amount of resources in rc file*/
    return TRUE;
}


BOOL EnumResourceNamesCallback(HMODULE applicationModule, LPCTSTR resourceType, LPTSTR resourceName, std::map<long /*languageId*/, std::map<long /*resource id (e.g. 1000, 7777, 1001)*/, std::string /*resource value*/>> *pResources)
{
    return EnumResourceLanguages(applicationModule, resourceType, resourceName, (ENUMRESLANGPROC)EnumResourceLanguagesCallback, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pResources));
}

int main()
{
    std::map<long /*languageId*/, std::map<long /*resource id (e.g. 1000, 7777, 1001)*/, std::string /*resource value*/>> resources;

    EnumResourceNames(::GetModuleHandleA(nullptr), RT_STRING, (ENUMRESNAMEPROC)EnumResourceNamesCallback, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&resources));
}
```

This gave me all handles to resources with ability to call LoadResource & LockResource, but from here it is unclear to me how to get

1. List of available resource ids for a given resource handle
2. Actually get a value of a resource

There seems to be something in the `wchar_t *data` after locking resource, but it doesn't seem to be structured in any way for `STRINGTABLE`, maybe it would work for binary resource, but `STRINGTABLE` format doesn't seem to be parsable

**What else I tried**

Just calling LoadString, but for that

1. I can't specify language (and I can't mess with system or application locale)
2. I do not know how to get available resource ids

EDIT:
Added more investigation towards getting data via LockResource

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040130-00/?p=40813. PS: can't find the original Q196774 article, Microsoft is getting rid of these old stuff :-(

Comment: @SimonMourier this looks very much like what I need! Thank you very, I will check if that still works same way.

Comment: @SimonMourier sorry for the late answer. This code works (to some extent), still can't find how to get resource ids & some resources are found twice with callback ( and since i don't know their ids - can't remove duplicates from the result map). But that's already a big progress, so feel free to post that as an answer so I can award you (feel free to use code from my answer or just reference it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STRING TABLE resources are somewhat documented here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040130-00/?p=40813

(PS: here's a link to the mentioned KB article Q196774 : https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/196774)

> The strings listed in the *.rc file are grouped together in bundles of
> sixteen. So the first bundle contains strings 0 through 15, the second
> bundle contains strings 16 through 31, and so on. In general, bundle N
> contains strings (N-1)*16 through (N-1)*16+15.
>
> The strings in each bundle are stored as counted UNICODE strings, not
> null-terminated strings. If there are gaps in the numbering, null
> strings are used. So for example if your string table had only strings
> 16 and 31, there would be one bundle (number 2), which consists of
> string 16, fourteen null strings, then string 31.

Here is some sample code that dumps all string resources from a given file:

```
void DumpStringTable(LPCWSTR filePath)
{
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibraryEx(filePath, nullptr, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    if (!hModule)
    {
        wprintf(L"LoadLibraryEx failed err: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    if (!EnumResourceTypesEx(hModule, EnumResType, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        wprintf(L"EnumResourceTypesEx failed err: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    FreeLibrary(hModule);
}

BOOL EnumresLang(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR lpType, LPCWSTR lpName, WORD wLanguage, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    if (lpType == RT_STRING)
    {
        const HRSRC res = FindResourceEx(hModule, lpType, lpName, wLanguage);
        if (!res)
        {
            wprintf(L"FindResourceEx failed err: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }

        const DWORD size = SizeofResource(hModule, res);
        if (!size)
        {
            wprintf(L"SizeofResource failed err: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }

        HGLOBAL hMem = LoadResource(hModule, res);
        if (!hMem)
        {
            wprintf(L"LoadResource failed err: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }

        LPWORD data = (LPWORD)LockResource(hMem);
        if (!data)
        {
            wprintf(L"LockResource failed err: %u\n", GetLastError());
            return FALSE;
        }

        const WORD nameInt = (WORD)(((ULONG_PTR)lpName) & 0xFFFF);
        for (WORD i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            const WORD len = *data;
            data++;
            if (len)
            {
                const WORD id = (nameInt - 1) * 16 + i;
                std::wstring str;
                str.append((const wchar_t*)data, len);
                data += len;
                wprintf(L"id:%u: %s\n", id, str.c_str());
            }
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL EnumResName(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR lpType, LPWSTR lpName, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    if (!EnumResourceLanguagesEx(hModule, lpType, lpName, EnumresLang, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        wprintf(L"EnumResourceLanguagesEx failed err: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL EnumResType(HMODULE hModule, LPWSTR lpType, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    if (!EnumResourceNamesEx(hModule, lpType, EnumResName, 0, 0, 0))
    {
        wprintf(L"EnumResourceNamesEx failed err: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiple-Language Resources loading in windows apps is done by

1. Set locale using SetThreadLocale API.
2. Call LoadResource (Or more specific APIs like LoadMenu, LoadString)

To load a resource, its ID should be known. If you want to enumerate all resources use EnumResource* APIs.

Comment: Hello @nkvs, thank you for your answer. It doesn't fit me because I can't use SetThreadLocale api & I don't even know all the locales for which I have resources.

Comment: In these cases, you need to define fallback. Or maintain a list of supported language for you application. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/creating-a-multilingual-user-interface-application for example

Answer (score -1):

Following link provided by @SimonMourier I've written the code which reads all resources.

`EnumResourceLanguagesCallback` may be called multiple times even for a single resource file, it seems to be parsing around 33-34 resources per call, but it may register some resources twice for some reason.

This code still can't get resource id.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

BOOL EnumResourceLanguagesCallback(HMODULE applicationModule, LPCTSTR resourceType, LPCTSTR resourceName, WORD languageId, std::map<long /*languageId*/, std::map<unsigned long /*resource id (e.g. 1000, 7777, 1001)*/, std::wstring /*resource value*/>> *pResources)
{
    HRSRC hResInfo = FindResourceEx(applicationModule, resourceType, resourceName, languageId);
    HGLOBAL hData = LoadResource(applicationModule, hResInfo);

    if (NULL != hData)
    {
        DWORD resourceSize = SizeofResource(applicationModule, hResInfo);
        wchar_t* data = (wchar_t*)LockResource(hData);

        size_t offset = 0;
        while (offset < resourceSize) {

            const wchar_t *resourceValue = data + offset;
            if (resourceValue != nullptr)
            {
                const size_t dataSize = static_cast<size_t>(*resourceValue);
                if (dataSize > 0 && (offset + dataSize) < resourceSize) {
                    std::wstring value;
                    value.assign(resourceValue + 1, dataSize);

                    // TODO how to get resource id ???
                    long id = (*pResources)[languageId].size();

                    (*pResources)[languageId][id] = value;
                }
                offset += dataSize;
            }

            offset++;
        }

        UnlockResource(data);
    }

    return TRUE;
}


BOOL EnumResourceNamesCallback(HMODULE applicationModule, LPCTSTR resourceType, LPTSTR resourceName, std::map<unsigned long /*languageId*/, std::map<long /*resource id (e.g. 1000, 7777, 1001)*/, std::wstring /*resource value*/>> *pResources)
{
    return EnumResourceLanguages(applicationModule, resourceType, resourceName, (ENUMRESLANGPROC)EnumResourceLanguagesCallback, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pResources));
}

int main()
{
    std::map<unsigned long /*languageId*/, std::map<long /*resource id (e.g. 1000, 7777, 1001)*/, std::wstring /*resource value*/>> resources;

    EnumResourceNames(::GetModuleHandleA(nullptr), RT_STRING, (ENUMRESNAMEPROC)EnumResourceNamesCallback, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(&resources));

    return 0;
}
```